# Powershell climb directory tree backwards

Tags: powershell

I have script located in `C:\projects\bacon\packages\build\run.ps1` and I am trying to locate the solution folder (in this case bacon). Everything I've found shows how to climb forward if you know the folder name. But I don't know the project name, so I need to climb backwards until I find the first containing folder that has a packages or dependencies folder within the given script's path.

The closest function I've found is to use `Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` to get my script's path and perhaps loop backwards somehow? but I can't find anyway of looping the folders backwards until I find the "packages" or "dependencies" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`. `Get-Item` returns an object that has a `Parent` property.  You can limit `Get-ChildItem` to just directory objects. You can then use this to trek backwards:

```
$current = Get-Item .
Write-Host $Current.Parent
do
{
    $parent = Get-Item $current.Parent.FullName
    $childDirectories = $parent | Get-ChildItem -Directory | ? { $_.Name -in @("dependencies","packages") }
    $current = $parent
} until ($childDirectories)
$bacon = $parent.FullName
```

I should say that the first line `$current = Get-Item .` will only work as is if the current path for the PowerShell runspace is at the end of the tree you are working with.

In your script, if you are using v3, you can replace the `.` with `$PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: Doesn't work? Getting this error: Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Projects\Bacon\release3.5\Dependencies\BuildScripts\run.ps1:4 char:24
+     $parent = Get-Item $current.Parent.FullName
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running this in? Also, if the runspace is starting in a root folder (e.g. C:\) than the parent property will be blank.

Comment: According to $PSVersionTable.PSVersion - 3.0

Comment: Added some code to the original sample to help figure this out, If the parent property is null, you are either in a different PSProvider than the file system or at a root drive.

Comment: Error: Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Projects\Bacon\release3.5\Dependencies\BuildScripts\test.ps1:5 char:24
+     $parent = Get-Item $current.Parent.FullName
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: Can you trace through the script? Debug it in the ISE and see what the first value of `$current` is.

Comment: It looks like it found the foldername, but it never stopped running.

Comment: Then that means that no folder in your path has folders called "dependencies" or "packages".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55069/discussion-between-yycdev-and-joseph-alcorn).